# ios 8 custom keyboard Appear with Delay

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, custom-keyboard

I have created custom keyboard with Objective c and used nib file for Keyboard design, my issue is that when I Change keyboard to my custom Keyboard it appears with some delay, I tried many scenario but not get any Success. Please help me to resolve that, help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AutoLayout try to layout your subviews manually. For me my keyboard appeared instantly without delay when i quitted AutoLayout. Before I had  I had a delay of about one second.

For example:
first row of keyboard: q w e r t z u i o p
q had a leading space of 15 px
p had a trailing space of 15 px
q w e r t z u i o p had a spacing of 5 px and they had the same width

Instead of using constraints, you can easily code it yourself in layoutSubviews of your views KeyboardViewController:

```
    NSUInteger numberOfRows = 4;
    CGFloat horizontalSpacing = 5.0;
    CGFloat verticalSpacing = 12.0;
    CGFloat leadingSpacingFirstRow = 3.0;
    CGFloat trailingSpacingFirstRow = 3.0;
    CGFloat topPadding = 25.0;
    CGFloat bottomPadding = 3.0;
    CGFloat width = ( self.bounds.size.width - leadingSpacingFirstRow - trailingSpacingFirstRow - horizontalSpacing * (numberOfButtonsFirstRow - 1) ) / numberOfButtonsFirstRow;
    CGFloat height = ( self.bounds.size.height - topPadding - bottomPadding - verticalSpacing * (numberOfRows - 1) ) / numberOfRows;
```

Now you can place the buttons in your view:

```
    // create row 1
    for (NSUInteger i=0; i<numberOfButtonsFirstRow; i++) {
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(leadingSpacingFirstRow + i * width + i * horizontalSpacing, topPadding, width, height)];

        [self addSubview:v];
    }
```

This sight might help you
[the-trials-and-tribulations-of-writing-a-3rd-party-ios-keyboard](http://beta-blog.archagon.net/2014/11/08/the-trials-and-tribulations-of-writing-a-3rd-party-ios-keyboard/)